# Mvc service pattern best practice

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

So I am thinking what would be the best way to implement this.

I have 2 services in my domain layer of my mvc application. These services are responsible for the business logic validations. So let's say that in the first service (we ll call it product service) we have this:

```
public bool save(viewmodel vm)
{
    Validate(vm)
    if (!vm.hasErrors)
    {
        //map the viewmodel to the model and save
        return repo.save(vm)
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now when saving for example in the second service I want to save a product object.

What would be the best way to implement this?

1) Should the second service call the first one? ( if yes should I dependency inject it into the second one)

2) Should the controller be injected with those 2 services and use them appropriately ?

I actually like the first solution (unless there is another one), and this because I have in mind to keep my controllers with no business logic at all.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Think about separation of concerns, and you will use the second option :

- product service is responsible for product validation / save
- any other service would have its own responsibility, but does not care about products
- your controller is in charge of saving product + other stuff, it's the one who needs to know (injection) both your services